# How to calculate the average voltage and VRMS of a non sinusoidal waveform

Tags: ac, dc, waveform, rms, sinusoidal

[image]

I need to calculate the average voltage and VRMS of this.

It's given that Vp=41V, Vn=-6V and T=13ms.

I know the answer for the average voltage is 12.8V, but I can't find the formula that gets this result anywhere, same thing about the VRMS value.

Comment: [I tell you how to do it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/663397/330261). But for 75%. It's trivial to re-arrange for any duty cycle, though. Such as 40%.

Comment: Just added the given values, as this is a beginner class I feel like the answer should be simpler than these.

Comment: It comes down to area under the curve. The calculus equations with integrals are the same thing but are able to handle graphs you can't figure out the area simply by counting the squares as you can in your example graph. What beginner class is this? Because the question cannot be answered without the concept of integrals as a pre-requisite. You may not need to actually crunch through the equations given that the area under the curve in the question is countable, but you do need to understand the concept of what the equations are saying.

Comment: @DKNguyen This is first year of Information and Electrical Engineering, maybe not beginner class, but beginner question because you are not expected to solve the integrals. But I can't figure out how to solve this without them, what do you mean exactly with it comes down to the area under the curve.

Comment: I never said you are expected to solve integrals for this question. I specifically said said that you only needed to understand the concept of the integral equations and then count the area under the graph according to what the equations say. As in \$\int_0^T f(x)\$ means the area under the curve f(x) over the interval 0 and T.

Comment: And calculus should have been a pre-requisite for an electrical engineering program. However you would not have learned the specific expression for average or RMS (especially RMS) in a general calculus course. That should have come up prior to being presented this question in the electrical engineering course. Did the course not tell you how to solve such a problem before throwing it at you?

Comment: The graph is garbage though. The Y scaling does not match the values given. Four units = 41V but 2 units = -6V? But I do get 12.8V average though. Did not bother to calculate the RMS.

Comment: This is a good answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648954/how-do-you-calculate-the-average-current-of-a-square-wave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average:

For rectangular waveforms, multiply the voltage by the percentage of time at each value, add them up.

41 * 40% + (-6) * 60% = 12.8

RMS:

For rectangular waveforms, use a similar process, except square the voltages before averaging, then squareroot the result.

Square:
41^2 = 1681
(-6)^2 = 36

Mean (Average):
1681 * 40% + 36 * 60% = 694

Root:
square root of 694 is 26.34

Answer (score 3):

Since you were unable to find a "formula", I'll derive one here, but for the TLDR, just go to the end.

For a periodic waveform \$f\$, like a sinusoid \$f(t) = sin(t)\$, the way to find the average is to integrate the signal over a single cycle, and then divide by the period of that cycle:

$$ M = \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^{T}{f(t)\cdot dt} $$

If you have a non-continuous waveform, like a square or rectangle, this isn't going to work, because there's no single continuous, integrable function that describes it, due to the instantaneous rises and falls. However, you can split the wave into partitions, each being a section of the waveform that *can* be described as a continuous integrable function, and integrate "piece-wise":

$$ \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^{T}{f(t)\cdot dt} = \frac{1}{T}\left[\int_{t=0}^{t_1}{f(t)\cdot dt} + \int_{t=t_1}^{T}{f(t)\cdot dt}\right] $$

If you look closely, the section inside the square brackets is just the sum of two integrals, taken over intervals \$0<t<t1\$, and \$t_1<t<T\$, where \$t_1\$ is some instant in time within a single cycle. The first integral operates on the function prior to time \$t=t_1\$, and the second integral operates on the waveform following that instant. You can define as many partitions, or "pieces", as you want.

For a rectangular wave, though, we need only two intervals, the first being where the signal is at one potential (a constant value \$V_P\$ in your case), and the second where the signal has some other value (such as \$V_N\$). I will call these values \$Y_1\$ and \$Y_2\$, which are two constants representing the values of our rectangular function in each interval.

Considering that time \$t=0\$ represents the beginning the first partition, time \$t=t_1\$ is the instant where the first partition ends and the second one begins, and time \$t=T\$ is the end of the second partition, we can define the durations of each partition \$T_1\$ and \$T_2\$ to be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
T_1 = t_1 - 0 \\ \\
T_2 = T - t_1 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Let's integrate during the first interval:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_1(t) &= Y_1 \\ \\
\int_{t=0}^{t_1}{f_1(t)\cdot dt} &= \int_{t=0}^{t_1}{Y_1\cdot dt}\\ \\
&= \left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}Y_1\cdot t\right]_0^{t_1} \\ \\
&= Y_1 (t_1 - 0) \\ \\
&= Y_1T_1
\end{aligned}
$$

During the second interval:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_2(t) &= Y_2 \\ \\
\int_{t=t_1}^T{f_2(t)\cdot dt} &= \int_{t=t_1}^T{Y_2\cdot dt}\\ \\
&= \left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}Y_2\cdot t\right]_{t_1}^T \\ \\
&= Y_2 (T - t_1) \\ \\
&= Y_2T_2
\end{aligned}
$$

Plugging these into the piece-wise integral from before, mean \$M\$ will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
M &= \frac{1}{T}\left[\int_{t=0}^{t_1}{f_1(t)\cdot dt} + \int_{t=t_1}^{T}{f_2(t)\cdot dt}\right] \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{T}\left[Y_1T_1 + Y_2T_2\right] \\ \\
&= Y_1\frac{T_1}{T} + Y_2\frac{T_2}{T} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Notice that \$\frac{T_1}{T}\$ is the fraction of a complete cycle that the function spends with value \$Y_1\$. Likewise, \$\frac{T_2}{T}\$ represents the fraction of the cycle spent at \$Y_2\$. If I define \$D\$ to be the former, called the "duty cycle", then we have:

$$ \frac{T_1}{T} = D $$

\$T_2\$ must be the *remaining* fraction of *one* cycle:

$$ \frac{T_2}{T} = 1-D $$

Substituting those into our equation for the mean:

$$
\begin{aligned}
M &= Y_1\frac{T_1}{T} + Y_2\frac{T_2}{T} \\ \\
&= Y_1D + Y_2(1-D)
\end{aligned}
$$

D is dimensionless, it's just a fraction of 1. That means for a periodic rectangular waveform, the mean value is completely independent of frequency or period. The same is true for *any* periodic waveform.

---

#### TLDR

The fraction of a complete cycle that your waveform spends at value \$V_P\$ is \$D=\frac{4}{10}\$ (I figured this out just by counting the squares; period \$T\$ is irrelevant here). The remaining time at \$V_N\$ is \$1-D=\frac{6}{10}\$.

Plug those into the equation we derived above:

$$
\begin{aligned}
M &= Y_1D + Y_2(1-D) \\ \\
&= 41\times \frac{4}{10} + (-6)\times \frac{6}{10} \\ \\
&= 12.8V
\end{aligned}
$$

RMS is the square **R**oot of the **M**ean of the **S**quare of the signal over one cycle. Importantly, the result of squaring a rectangular waveform is another rectangular waveform with the exact same duty cycle, so we can use the same formula derived above, with the same value for \$D\$, but with values \${V_P}^2\$ and \${V_N}^2\$ instead:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{RMS} &= \sqrt{{V_P}^2D + {V_N}^2(1-D)} \\ \\
&= \sqrt{1681\times \frac{4}{10} + 36\times \frac{6}{10}} \\ \\
&= \sqrt{694} \\ \\
&= 26.3V
\end{aligned}
$$